# How can we override the product ordering script

Tags: wordpress

I want to override the default action to sort the products by order by.
I just want to populate products via ajax without using external plugin. I want to implement an ajax request whenever selection of sort dropdown (by popularity, by average, by latest etc)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `woocommerce_catalog_orderby` filter you can change the options order.

Try this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'order_by_rating_first');

function order_by_rating_first($orderby) {

    if (array_key_exists('rating', $orderby)) {
        $rating = $orderby['rating'];
        unset($orderby['rating']);
        array_unshift($orderby, $rating);
    }

    return $orderby;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i want to do the sorting by ajax. how can i override the default product sorting.

Comment: Please, add some details and your code attempt, you never talked about ajax until now.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information i provided, i just want to populate products via ajax without using external plugin.
I want to implement an ajax request whenever selection of sort dropdown (by popularity, by average, by latest etc).